# On quit returns error mirc Script?

Tags: mirc

This section of code returns unknown command everytime somebody quits.

```
on 1:QUIT:#By_the_Sea_of_Thassa: {
  if ($read(txt\free.txt,nw,$nick)) {
    /write -dl $+ $readn txt\free.txt
  }
}
```

Any help in fixing in so when the user quits it removes them from the list would be appriecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not specify a channel after the `on quit` event.

So it should be:

```
on 1:QUIT: {
  if ($read(txt\free.txt,nw,$nick)) {
    write -dl $+ $readn txt\free.txt
  }
}
```

More info here: http://en.wikichip.org/wiki/mirc/on_events/on_quit